# Is there an elegant way to store a dual relationship (i.e. user 1 and user 2 are friends)

Tags: database, database-design, social-networking, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I've run into the same problem in two different pieces of work this month:

```
Version 1: User 1 & User 2 are friends
Version 2: Axis 1 & Axis 2 when graphed should have the quadrants colored...
```

The problem is, I don't see an elegant way, using a RDBMS, to store and query this information.

There are two obvious approaches:

Approach 1:

```
store the information twice (i.e. two db rows rows per relationship):
u1, u2, true 
u2, u1, true
u..n, u..i, true
u..i, u..n, true

have rules to always look for the inverse on updates: 
on read, no management needed
on create, create inverse
on delete, delete inverse
on update, update inverse

Advantage:    management logic is always the same.
Disadvantage: possibility of race conditions, extra storage (which is admittedly cheap, but feels wrong)
```

Approach 2:

```
store the information once (i.e. one db row per relationship)
u1, u2, true
u..n, u..i, true

have rules to check for corollaries:
on read, if u1, u2 fails, check for u2, u1 
on create u1, u2: check for u2, u1, if it doesn't exist, create u1, u2
on delete, no management needed
on update, optionally redo same check as create

Advantage: Only store once
Disadvantage: Management requires different set of cleanup depending on the operation
```

I'm wondering if there's a 3rd approach that goes along the lines of "key using f(x,y) where f(x,y) is unique for every x,y combination and where f(x,y) === f(y,x)"

My gut tells me that there should be some combination of bitwise operations that can fulfill these requirements.  Something like a two-column:

key1 = x && y
key2 = x + y

I'm hoping that people who spent more time in the math department, and less time in the sociology department have seen a proof of the possibility or impossibility of this and can provide a quick "[You moron,] its easily proven (im)possible, see this link"  (name calling optional)

Any other elegant approach would also be very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not use a Graph based database? Neo4j for instance. This would allow you to fully capture your graph relationships. You can also use Mongo and store it all in a Json Object.

Comment: This is something not even 'document-oriented' aka 'NoSQL' databases support elegantly.

Comment: @steve yes, Neo4j is a real option (though i'm not a huge fan of their license).  Neo4j abstracts this, but they've got to solve the fundamental problem somehow.  I'd like to understand how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also a way to use the 2nd approach by adding an extra constraint. Check that `u1 < u2`:

```
CREATE TABLE User
( Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (Name)
) ;

CREATE TABLE MutualFriendship
( u1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, u2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (u1, u2)
, FOREIGN KEY (u1) 
    REFERENCES User(Name)
, FOREIGN KEY (u2) 
    REFERENCES User(Name)
, CHECK (u1 < u2) 
) ;
```

The rules to read, create, insert or update will have to use the `(LEAST(u1,u2), GREATEST(u1,u2))`.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Check doens't work in MySQL, could use a Trigger instead.

Comment: @santiagobasulto: Thnx, the question was DBMS-agnostic. It won't be easy to implement in MySQL (especially if one dislikes triggers ...)

Comment: @ypercube Yes! You're right. I was just mentioning it. It's true that will get hard with the triggers too.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL it's easy to implement the constraints to support your first approach:

```
CREATE TABLE MutualFriendship
(u1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 u2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (u1,u2),
 FOREIGN KEY (u2,u1) REFERENCES MutualFriendship (u1,u2));

INSERT INTO MutualFriendship VALUES
('Alice','Bob'),
('Bob','Alice');
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that's interested, I played around with a few bitwise operations and found that the following seems to fulfill the criteria for f(x,y):

```
#Python, returns 3 tuple
def get_hash(x, y):
  return (x & y, x | y, x * y)
```

I can't prove it, though.

Comment: If x and y are integers (or belong to a set that can be fully ordered), you could use `(min(x,y), max(x,y))`

Comment: @ypercube, you're absolutely right.  even the math classes I took should have allowed me to see that.  Thanks again.

Comment: Still, your hash function makes an interesting math problem. Are there two (x,y) couples with same hash?

Answer (score 0):

"x is a friend of y".

Define a table of (x,y) pairs and enforce a canonical form, e.g. x<y.  This will ensure that you cannot have both (p,q) and (q,p) in your database, thus it will ensure "store once".

Create a view as SELECT x,y FROM FRIENDS   UNION   SELECT x as y, y as x FROM FRIENDS.

Do your updates against the base table (downside : updaters must be aware of the enforced canonical form), do your queries against the view.

Answer (score -2):

You seem to limit the number of friends to 1. If this is the case then I would use something like
u1,u2
u2,u1
u3,null
u4,u5
u5,u4

u3 does not have a friend.

Comment: no, each u1, u2 combination is a row.  n users can have n-1 friends (or n friends if you don't explicitly disallow self friending)