# Efficient way to store unordered pair in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am working with twitter data and need to store uid and friendId pair in a mysql table. My purpose is to create a network of friends and followers with the help of the table later.

I want to avoid duplicate pairs like (uid, friendId) and (friendId, uid) in the table.

Thank you

Comment: [Is there an elegant way to store a dual relationship (i.e. user 1 and user 2 are friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808994/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-store-a-dual-relationship-i-e-user-1-and-user-2-are/8810099#8810099)

Comment: Store them as ordered (id2 > id1), and remember that they are in fact unordered.

Comment: @ypercube: I have once done this using the posgresql rule system. Very clean. Not for the faint at heart, don't try this at home.

Comment: @s2n: Please note (and sorry for the closing vote, just noticed the mysql tag) that the link is about SQL in general. **MySQL does not enforce `CHECK` constraints!**

Comment: @s2n: Please read the comments after that. The link is a general SQL answer that doesn't work as it is in MySQL :(

Comment: @ypercube: i know but its useful to know how to tackle the problem for SQL in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to avoid duplicate pairs do check `uid < friendId` before inserting.

Comment: simple and elegant. I think it will do the job. Thank you.

Comment: It's almost imposible to do this with MySQL. You have to do a Trigger BEFORE INSERT and provoke an error in there.

Comment: Unfortunately, @santiagobasulto is right. You can't enforce this constraint, as it is, in MySQL. (Even worse, MySQL will allow you to write it in the `CREATE TABLE` code, it will parse it, show no error and then **ignore** it!)

Comment: what i can do is make the pair (a,b) where a<b and check its existence before inserting. Dont know how efficient it will be for large tables.

Comment: Checking will not be slow. I guess you'll have a Unique index on the pair, anyway.

Comment: IMO: Two options. 1. Make the index unique and check in your application. 2. Use something else, Mongo for example. Or even better, use the right tool: https://github.com/twitter/flockdb